# How can I use json to populate the data in a google bar chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I am trying to use a [google bar chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/imagebarchart.html) in an asp.net-mvc application.

The sample is quite straight forward to do as a static table but i want to build up the table on the server side and pass back down to the client using ajax.

Is there anyway you can populate the datatable that is used for the bar chart with an ajax call getting json or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of these tools with jQuery ajax requests for example:

- http://keith-wood.name/gChart.html
- http://code.google.com/p/gchart-plugin/
- http://www.maxb.net/scripts/jgcharts/include/demo/

(You'd still need to construct the appropriate JSON representations on the server side.)